# Getting 1 or 0 value in materialize's switch class using Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, materialize, switching

How do I get a value of 1 if it is checked and a value of 0 if not using Typescript? I am using a materialize framework.

Here's the code for it:

```
  <div class='switch'>
      <label>
          Deactivate
          <input name='switch_Activate' type='hidden' value='0'>
          <input id='active' name='switch_Activate'
                 type='checkbox' onclick='onActive(this.id)' checked value='1'>
          <span class='lever'></span>
          Activate
      </label>
  </div>
```

function

```
onActive(){
```

}
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type="radio"` inputs and bind its to ngModel

```
<input type="radio" name="switch_Activate" [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="switchModel">
<input type="radio" name="switch_Activate" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="switchModel">
```